# Kubernetes, REST API and RabbitMQ (.NET)

Tags: .net, rest, kubernetes, rabbitmq, saga

I have a use case where I am using 2 pods (containers) running .NET Rest API. The rest API is developed by using SAGA pattern, therefore the http requests usually travels through the different microservices using RabbitMQ messages. Since pods share the same message queue name, it might happen that messages are accepted by different pods.

Q: Is there a way how to send response from pod that did not originaly received the http request message ? Is the http context required for response only in the original pod ? Can it somehow be shared ?

I already tried what I described above, but API is simply not sending response. Even though it succeeds, client ends up with the timeout.

Comment: `Is there a way how to send response from pod that did not originaly received the http request message?` How do you think, a pod is triggered to send a response? `Since pods share the same message queue name, it might happen that messages are accepted by different pods.` Which is perfectly OK, if pods of the same deployment do this. Your architecture seems off. But this whole question is far to broad for us to answer it.

Comment: I started to use specific names for the queues like queue_01 and queue_02 to send final message to that pod that will response to client, but I was curious if there is a way to use same queue name and to be able to send response from any of the pod regardles which pod received the http request.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to send a response from a pod that did not originally receive the HTTP request but, you can use a service mesh like Istio to manage inter pod communication.

In this case you can configure the service mesh to route requests to specific pods based on certain rules and allow pods to communicate with each other or you can share data between the pods by reverse proxy or a load balancer that can receive incoming requests and to determine which pod should handle the request and the pod that handles the request can then generate response and send it back to the intermediate component, which will forward response back to the client. You can explore distributed data stores as well.

Please check this [Document](https://kublr.com/blog/implementing-a-service-mesh-with-istio-to-simplify-microservices-communication/)